# $\int_0^T f(t)dt \geq \int_0^T \frac{t}{T} f(t) dt$ for all $T>0$ implying $f$ is nonnegative?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

Let $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^T f(t)dt \geq \int_0^T \frac{t}{T} f(t) dt
\end{equation}
for all $T \in (0,\infty)$.

Then, can I conclude that $f$ is non-negative? Or what kind of conclusion can I draw from the above inequality?

Comment: $f : t \mapsto (x-3)^2-1$ satisfies the assumption but is not non-negative.

Comment: Let us assume that the function is Positive & large between 0 & A , hence that Integral is very large. Then when it goes slightly Negative after A , then the RHS will reduce a little , while the LHS will reduce a lot because the Positive values have less weightage while the Negative values have more weightage. Hence your Criteria will be true , though the function has Negative values.